# How to set minimum and maximum of the x axis using iOS-Charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm trying to use ios-charts to draw charts and I have figured out how to set the minimum and maximum of the y axis. However, I have spent more than 5 hours and I still cannot set the minimum and maximum for the x axis. So can anyone help me?

The code I used to limit the y axis is like this

```
statsView.leftAxis.customAxisMax = 21.00
statsView.leftAxis.customAxisMin = 0.00
```

and there are just too more points on the screen
[too many data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G5rj.png)

Comment: Can you show your code & specify which library are you using? ( Edit your question please )

Comment: just did :( dunno if it's enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried below code, works for me.

```
lineChartView.xAxis.axisMinValue = 100;
lineChartView.xAxis.axisMaxValue = 200;
```